# Renounced ownership

Tags: solidity, remix, smart-contract-wallets

I have renounced ownership of smart contract and now it is a null address (0x00..). Is there a way for me to reclaim ownership? As currently if I call transferOwnership - it comes back with error that caller is not owner.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No

(it depends on the source code of the contract, but most likely no)